# Cypress intercept() fails when the network call has parameters with '/'

Tags: cypress, cypress-intercept

I need to add cy.wait() for some network call which has parameters having forward slashes in it.

eg: http://example.com/myPage1?id=598dccc6&startDate=10/01/2023&endDate=11/01/2023

For this, I've added the following intercept,

```
cy.intercept('http://example.com/myPage1**').as('myPage1');
```

However, `cy.wait('@myPage1').its('response.statusCode').should('eq',200);` is getting timed out and the test case fails.

What should I do?

Thanks.

---

Reply to @agoff

Somehow this doesn't work. My `baseUrl` is like `http://192.168.43.82/font-end/#/` and api calls are made to `http://192.168.43.82/rest/api/myPage` with query parameters.

I've tried

```
cy.intercept(
          {
            pathname:'/rest/api/myPage',
            method:'POST'
        }).as('myPage');
```

what's wrong with this?

Comment: Can you add you code like how did you use that intercept in your code? Did the intercept register before you wait for it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible to catch it with a regex expression for the URL.

You don't need to specify the base part `http://example.com`.

Chars `/` and `?` are operators in regex, so preceed them with `\` to indicate the literal character.

```js
cy.intercept(/\/myPage1\?/).as('myPage1')
```

---

Alternatively,

```js
cy.intercept({pathname: '**/myPage1'}, {}).as('myPage1')
```

Tested with baseUrl:

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
    baseUrl: 'http://192.168.43.82/font-end/#/'
  },
});
```

and the app fetching

```js
fetch('http://192.168.43.82/rest/api/myPage1?id=598dccc6&startDate=10/01/2023&endDate=11/01/2023')
```

Comment: Both of them work! Thank you so much.